# doesnt run for loop

Tags: excel, vba

Every part of this Code is executed but the part inside of the for loop on the top

I tried to rewrite this part of the code because one time it helped in vba but just this part would want to run

```
    Do While Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Overview").Cells(ovrow, ovcol))

        For row = 2 To length

            If Sheets(wsname).Cells(row, column) = Sheets("Overview").Cells(ovrow, ovcol) Then
                counter = counter + 1
            End If

        Next row

        Sheets("Overview").Cells(ovrow, ovcol).Offset(0, 1).value = counter
        counter = 0

        If Sheets("Overview").Cells(ovrow, ovcol).Offset(1, 0).value = "" Then
            ovrow = 2
            ovcol = ovcol + 2
            column = column + 1
        Else
            ovrow = ovrow + 1
        End If

        Cells(ovrow, ovcol).Select
    Loop
```

It should just count to the variable counter higher but nothing happens. I put some messageboxes inside my code so i can see where the code is in the excel cells but the counter variable stays at 0

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please see the rules of [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then please provide me with the full code, maybe `column` is `0` or something else outside the code is not right. You can use the VB-Editor to set Breakpoints at certain lines of the code, the code then stops executing. You can also display the `View`>`Locals Window` (Menubar on top) to see the values of the variables at this point of the code.

Comment: I used this tool, but it shows, that the variables have the right values but it doesnt start the for loop. A for loop is without a condition so why doesnt it just start

Comment: What is the value of `length`? If `lenght` is `2` or smaller then the for loop will not run.

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem was the length variable. I forget to check what happens, when the variable is below 2. Now i just put the value up and it works just fine

Comment: Great that it worked Tim, as I already said: Please check out the [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)-Site and Upvote comments or answers that are useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is the full code

```
Private Sub RefreshBtn_Click()
    Dim source As String
    Dim sourcerow As Integer
    Dim sourcecolumn As Integer
    Dim target As String
    Dim targetrow As Integer
    Dim targetcolumn As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    sourcerow = 2
    sourcecolumn = 1
    source = Sheets("Devices").Cells(sourcerow, sourcecolumn).value
    targetrow = 2
    targetcolumn = 3


    For i = 1 To 6
        Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(targetrow, targetcolumn))
            Cells(targetrow, targetcolumn).value = ""
            targetrow = targetrow + 1
        Loop
        targetrow = 2
        targetcolumn = targetcolumn + 2
    Next i

    targetrow = 2
    targetcolumn = 3

    For i = 1 To 6

        Do While Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Devices").Cells(sourcerow, sourcecolumn))
            source = Sheets("Devices").Cells(sourcerow, sourcecolumn).value
            Sheets("Overview").Cells(targetrow, targetcolumn).value = source
            sourcerow = sourcerow + 1
            targetrow = targetrow + 1
        Loop
       sourcecolumn = sourcecolumn + 1
       sourcerow = 2
       targetrow = 2
       targetcolumn = targetcolumn + 2

    Next i


    Dim length As Integer
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim column As Integer
    Dim yearnow As String
    Dim monthnow As String
    Dim daynow As String
    Dim wsname As String
    Dim readdate As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet


        daynow = Day(Now())
    If daynow > 20 Then
        monthnow = month(Now()) + 1
        If monthnow = "Januar" Then
        yearnow = Year(Now()) + 1
        End If
    Else
        monthnow = month(Now())
        yearnow = Year(Now())
    End If

    wsname = yearnow + MonthName(monthnow)

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name = wsname Then
        exist = True
    End If
    Next ws

    Sheets("Overview").Cells(2, 2).value = wsname

    row = 2
    column = 4
    length = 0


    If exist = True Then
     Do While Not IsEmpty(Sheets(wsname).Cells(row, column))
        row = row + 1
        length = length + 1
    Loop
    Else
    MsgBox "Für den aktuellen Monat sind keine Offenen Bestellung vorhanden"
    End If

    Dim counter As Integer
    counter = 0
    Dim ovrow As Integer
    Dim ovcol As Integer
    ovrow = 2
    ovcol = 3

    Do While Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Overview").Cells(ovrow, ovcol))
        For row = 2 To length
            If Sheets("Overview").Cells(ovrow, ovcol).value = Sheets(wsname).Cells(row, column).value Then
               counter = counter + 1
               MsgBox "hallo"
            End If
        Next row
        Sheets("Overview").Cells(ovrow, ovcol).Offset(0, 1).value = counter
        counter = 0
        If Sheets("Overview").Cells(ovrow, ovcol).Offset(1, 0).value = "" Then
        ovrow = 2
        ovcol = ovcol + 2
        column = column + 1
        Else
        ovrow = ovrow + 1
        End If
        Cells(ovrow, ovcol).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```